# My shift, alt, windows, and control key are all being mapped as shift. On one keyboard

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

Basically title. If I borrow my dads keyboard it works, and I can do things like open terminal using the shortcut, but with my keyboard I can't. I have a "AGPtek PC000006" keyboard. This doesn't happen in windows, or in virtual box, only when I'm actually running 14.04 Ubuntu. Any advice?

Comment: Answer here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/648798/ctrl-and-alt-works-as-shift