# CTRL and ALT works as SHIFT?

Tags: drivers, keyboard

A few hours ago, I installed Ubuntu 14.04 alongside Windows 7. 
Everything went fine, installed all my games and programs. But, then I realized that <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>  key combinations (as well as many others) do not work.

This is really annoying since I like to use <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd> for multitasking. Anyways, I realized that they were mapped as <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> because as you know, if you hold <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> and press any key, it will be in <kbd>CAPS</kbd>. So that's what happens when I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> or <kbd>ALT</kbd>.

It's a custom-built desktop. I'm using a GAMDIAS USB keyboard.

`sudo lsusb`

```
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0c45:7603 Microdia 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1b80:b40c Afatech 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. 4-port hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 009 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 003: ID 1532:0504 Razer USA, Ltd 
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Could you add more info, about your hardware, is it a laptop? Which brand & model? Are you using USB keyboard?

Comment: It's a custom-built desktop. I'm using a GAMDIAS USB keyboard.

Comment: Open terminal then run `sudo lsusb` then edit you question. (look at bottom of the post there is an [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/648798/edit)  link. )

Comment: There you go...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Install driver from https://github.com/Swoogan/aziokbd

   ```
    sudo apt-get install mercurial build-essential linux-headers-generic dkms
    hg clone https://bitbucket.org/Swoogan/aziokbd
    cd aziokbd
    sudo ./install.sh dkms
   ```
2. Add kernel option to grub to prevent `usbhid` from being used for this keyboard. Append:

   ```
    usbhid.quirks=0x0c45:0x7603:0x4
   ```

   to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` in `/etc/default/grub`.

   Example:

   ```
    GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash usbhid.quirks=0x0c45:0x7603:0x4"
   ```
3. Update grub

   ```
    sudo update-grub
   ```
4. Reboot

**References:**

- [CTRL and ALT keys mapped to Shift for some reason](https://askubuntu.com/questions/572394/ctrl-and-alt-keys-mapped-to-shift-for-some-reason)
- [dkms Installed kernel module but not working after reboot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/605251/dkms-installed-kernel-module-but-not-working-after-reboot)
- [Prevent usbhid from claiming USB device](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55495/prevent-usbhid-from-claiming-usb-device)

Comment: This workaround will stop working after each kernel update. I described issue [here](http://askubuntu.com/q/785615/25831). Do you have any solution? Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by appending it? should I use `&`, `;` or just add it directly. I'm sorry if this is naive. It would be great if you could show how the line looks for you.

Comment: @AnkitSinghaniya , use space as separator. :) no problem I added full example of the modified line.

Comment: @DummyBeginner somehow late just noticed your comment. Check if installed it using DKMS. Verify using `dkms status` , is it listed there?

Comment: If anyone is getting a 404 on the bitbucket link, [there's a modified version on github](https://github.com/teitss/aziokbd) which worked for me.

Comment: @Meta Thank you, I update the answer with mirror that seem from same original author, in github.