# Keyboard fails to work after failed driver install

Tags: 14.04, drivers, usb, keyboard

[CTRL and ALT works as SHIFT?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/648798/ctrl-and-alt-works-as-shift)

I was following the answer to this question, as I myself was having a similar issue with my Gamdias keyboard. Unfortunately, not only did it not work, now the entire keyboard doesn't work (not even the <kbd>NUM LOCK</kbd> key light changes, the keys light up though).

What could I do to undo any changes done?

I am running 14.04.

Comment: What you could do denpends on what you've done. If you can't remember then this question is unanswerable.

Comment: @CelticWarrior I did the steps laid out in the link I linked.

Comment: Is yours also `0c45:7603 Microdia`? If the number is different it may still work with the same drivers but step 2 has to be changed accordingly. Please check, run `lsusb`, edit and update your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can tell you how to revert the changes described in [this answer](/a/648809/175814):

1. Unload the `aziokbd` kernel module:

   ```
   sudo modprobe -r aziokbd
   sudo dkms remove -m aziokbd -v 1.0.0
   ```
2. Remove `/etc/modprobe.d/usbhid.conf`:

   ```
   sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/usbhid.conf
   ```
3. Edit `/etc/default/grub` with your favourite text editor as super-user and remove the `usbhid.quirks=0x0c45:0x7603:0x4` from the variable `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`.
4. Update Grub:

   ```
   sudo update-grub
   ```
5. Reboot.

This will revert the changes however I can't tell if this will resolve your issue since I'm not sure by what it's caused.