# Ctrl, Super and Alt buttons act like Shift

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, shortcut-keys

I have a DEX Ltk-020 keyboard, and I am having trouble with its key mappings.

The
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Super</kbd>, and <kbd>Alt</kbd> keys all act like <kbd>Shift</kbd>.

I tried to change the input language, keyboard layout, etc... But I was not able to get the right key mappings for my keyboard.

I am getting crazy because without <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> I cannot for example use the key combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>

Can someone please help me with this problem?

I also tried this, since I am having the same problem:
[CTRL and ALT works as SHIFT?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/648798/ctrl-and-alt-works-as-shift)

But it did not work for my keyboard =(