# CTRL, ALT and WINDOWS KEY work the same way as SHIFT

Tags: drivers, xubuntu, keyboard

I have Xubuntu 16.04 and have recently bought a new keyboard -- [MODECOM VOLCANO GAMER](http://modecom.com/en/volcano-gamer-2/). I plugged it and it works great except the fact that <kbd>CTRL</kbd>, <kbd>ALT</kbd> and <kbd>WINDOWS KEY</kbd> work the same way as <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> does. It means I ma unable to use most keyboard shortcuts.

I tried a solution posted on this website, but unfortunately it did not work: [CTRL and ALT works as SHIFT?](https://askubuntu.com/a/648809/721023)

`sudo lsusb` output:

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0dd8:ac00 Netac Technology Co., Ltd 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 2109:0812 VIA Labs, Inc. VL812 Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0bda:57cc Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0489:e09f Foxconn / Hon Hai 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:c534 Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 258a:1006  
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 2109:2812 VIA Labs, Inc. VL812 Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think problem is with default anti-ghosting setting. I am using Mint 18.2 and I had same problem with [MODECOM VOLCANO GAMER](http://modecom.com/en/volcano-gamer-2/) keyboard on my system. By default keyboard have 87 anti-ghosting keys enabled. After I switched to 6 anti-ghosting keys, it works like charm (Fn + SL | key between PS and PB, it has 6/104key label on it).

Comment: Darn it worked! Thank you! I was pulling my hair over this and I would compile drivers myself or bougth new keyboard before I would try this! :D

Answer (score 0):

i feel that you should look into have they correct keyboard layout in use.
I could be wrong with that, but have had problems with that myself before and that solved it.