# 19.10: CTRL, ALT and SUPER function as SHIFT instead in Kubuntu but work AOK in Windows

Tags: drivers, usb, keyboard

I recently installed Kubuntu 19.10 as a secondary operating system. Everything seemed ok at first, until I realised that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>, and <kbd>WinKey</kbd>  (AKA <kbd>Super</kbd>) weren't behaving properly with my [Hanzo KB-1000G keyboard](http://pc-professional.info/keyboards/wired-keyboards/856-element-keyboard-kb1000g.html).

I opened up an online keyboard tester only to find out they were all mapped as my Shift key. I've tried following the solution, showed [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/648798/ctrl-and-alt-works-as-shift), changing the keyboard ID to represent mine and it did not work. Showkey gives me the same keycode for all of them. My lsusb output is:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 145f:01bd Trust Trust Wireless Mouse
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 046d:c534 Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0c45:760a Microdia USB Keyboard
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

How do I troubleshoot this so <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>, and <kbd>Super</kbd> work properly?

Comment: 1) I haven't tried another keyboard yet, but I haven't had any problems with it, when I'm using it on Windows 2) I just did, the sha256 are the same

Comment: For troubleshooting purposes, please try a different keyboard. Device recognition by the kernel is involved, and therefore testing with a different keyboard model would be very helpful.

Comment: @K7AAY I've just plugged in a Microsoft Wireless Desktop 2000 and all keys in that keyboard work as intended

Answer (score 1):

Since testing with a Microsoft Wireless Desktop 2000 showed all keys in that keyboard work as intended, this is a hardware issue which may require a custom driver from the manufacturer.

Comment: But since the Hanzo keyboard works as intented on Windows, how's this not a driver issue?

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar keyboard. You need to install this:

[Aziokbd](https://bitbucket.org/Swoogan/aziokbd/src/default/)

Comment: I tried installing it, but it didn't work. What ID does you keyboard have?